# HP Array Utility, Remove a spare drive from a Raid 1 Array

Tags: hp-smart-array, raid1

I have a DL380 with 2 Raid 1 arrays with spares. As the server is a part of a cluster I want to remove the spares and create a new logical drive with them.  The problem is that HP Array Configuration Manager doesn't allow this.

In the utility it says "Spare Management: Add and Remove spare physical drives."  But once in that utility the only options are to. Dedicate a spare drive, or to set it to auto replace.  There is no remove drive option.

Also there is no create logical drive option within the array.  Do I need to have an allocated drives before this option is available?

I have found documentation to tell me how to do all this but there are no screen shots with the documentation and the menu items just aren't there in the interface.  Any idea if I need a spare drive to make this menu item available or is it a security issue a bug or am I just misunderstanding the menu options.

Maybe if I just pull the drives and replace them they will become unassigned. Suckit and see is really not a practice I would recommend myself.

I have seen the unassigned command in the command line interface but can't find the download for Win 2008 on the internet.

Can anyone point me in the right direction

Thanks 
Ads

Comment: Is it a P410i controller?

Comment: I have found this post for you which details using the HP ACU to remove a spare. 

http://serverfault.com/questions/430593/repurpose-spare-drive-in-hp-proliant-raid-5-array

Comment: Thanks Tom,  I had found this post, but the GUI doesn't have the supporting menu commands the post claims. Unfortunately the Command Line Interfaces is not at that addresses in the post anymore, I will be happy to use the CLI but it isn't on the machine or on the ISO image I just downloaded from HP with the GUI.

Comment: I think this is what you need which says you will be able to choose the CLI when booted from it. https://h20566.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?idx=&action=driverDocument&itemLocale=&swItemId=MTX_3c888073127c4c65b7bd8559eb&mode=

Comment: Thanks Tom, this was the ISO image I was talking about, I went through it and there is no CLI, just drivers mainly Linux.  Its funny you would think that the GUI would make function calls through the CLI anyway, but it is not the case.  Making SCSI Bios level changes to a functioning server with a reboot will be my last resort. I will continue to look around for the CLI hpacucli.exe  I have a strange feeling that HP have re pachaged it as under a different name and that is why I can't find it.  Any more help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Hmmm, its supposed to be in that ISO. I will burn it and take a look myself on a spare DL180 G6 with a P410i I have lying around tommorrow morning.

Comment: Hey Tom, I found the solution. Its a false negitive. In the GUI you chose "Manage Spare Drives", There is no option to remove, you select the status quo, in my case "Dedicate Spare Drives" Then below you have a graphic of the drives, with grey for selected and white for unselected. You click the drive changing it to white then click on the next. It then saves your selection (or unselection). It is just a semantics issue but I'm cautious when it comes to a live server.  Thanks for all your help. Hopefully it will help you out some day.  Adam

Comment: No worries adam! Glad you got it sorted.