# Remove spare from OS array, add to data array

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hp-proliant, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array

OK, from what I've been seeing online (including at this link [Repurpose spare drive in HP ProLiant RAID 5 array](https://serverfault.com/questions/430593/repurpose-spare-drive-in-hp-proliant-raid-5-array)) it should be pretty simple to do what I need. I just want to get confirmation, since I haven't dealt with RAID arrays in years (when nothing like this was possible).

Basically, we have a ProLiant DL380 G7, running version 8.70.9.0 of the Array Config Utility. We have 2 arrays setup on it as:
Array A
 - 2 600 GB drives in RAID 1

Array B
 - 5 600 GB drives in RAID 5

- 1 600 GB drive as a shared spare

The server itself is a Server 2008 R2 Hyper-V host, holding the DC, file server, and SCCM DP for a smaller site. However, the Hyper-V host is down to about 50 GB's of free space. What we were thinking as a temporary fix (until they can purchase a new server next year), is to remove the spare, and add it to Array B to increase the available space.

Again, from what I can tell online, removing the spare and adding it to and expanding Array B should all be possible while the server is running. Just Manage Spare Drives, uncheck the drive in Bay 8 (it looks like I need to uncheck it for both arrays?), then after that's done add it to Array B and extend it.

Can anyone tell me if I have any incorrect information or assumptions?
  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct, and is entirely possible as long as there's a cache module on your Smart Array P410 controller and the battery/flash module is healthy.

This operation can be performed online, but please understand the the extension of Array B won't be possible until the RAID5 is "transformed" (basically, the data needs to be redistributed across the new set of disks). That portion may take awhile.

Comment: Are you referring to this information? Also, the part about extending Array B taking a while is understood, and expected, but thanks.

Array Accelerator
Array Accelerator Present Yes
Cache Status OK
Array Accelerator (Cache) Ratio 25% Read / 75% Write
Total Cache Size 1024 MB
Cache Backup Power Source Capacitor
Battery/Capacitor Pack Count  1
Battery/Capacitor Status OK

Comment: Okay. You should be fine.